# No_CLR_Support C++ project with a C++/CLI source file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr, mixed-mode

We have a VS2010 C++ project with **No Common Language Runtime Support** set in its project properties. Then I see that it has a source file containing some managed code and the properties for this file has "/clr" flag set. So the project does not have a /clr flag but a file inside it has. I am confused as to whether it makes the project a mixed mode one? I can open the output file in ILDisassembler which makes me believe that it indeed is a .NET assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely normal, a C++/CLI project very commonly contains a mix of native C++ and C++/CLI source code files.  The setting in the General setting pages merely sets the default that the compiler will assume.  But turning it on for each individual source file is quite valid and common.

Other ways to do this is to keep the native C++ code in a separate library project and link it.  Or by turning on MSIL code generation on and off on-the-fly in a single source code file by using #pragma managed.

The linker doesn't have to be told about it, it can tell from the content of the object file.  And yes, you will get a mixed-mode .NET assembly.  With the C++/CLI bits compiled to MSIL and the native C++ code compiled to machine code.

Comment: That means the application which was believed to be a pure c++ application is a mixed-mode one and has dependency on .NET FW. :D

Comment: Technically that's not accurate.  A native C++ application can load such a DLL just fine and use its normal native entrypoints without ever loading the .NET Framework.  Nothing in your question gives any hint that this is the case.  Use the debugger, look at its Debug > Windows > Modules window.  If you see clr.dll or mscorwks.dll then you do have a .NET dependency.

Comment: There is no separate DLL, its just one project with NO_CLR set in its properties and one of the .cpp file inside it has /clr set.